# Why there are written randomly null characters in some of my output files?

Tags: linux, bash, null, cron, cobol

I have some scripts in my RedHat server which contains Microfocus COBOL programs which generates a huge file of aprox 3GB in a sort of time of 3 hours on average. The programs write their output files directly in the directory `/my_test/files/`.

The problem is that sometimes (randomly) some files generated contains null character sections in the middle of the file. And when I check them up, if I reexecute the script again (with the same input parameters), the output file is perfectly generated (it doesn't contain any nullchars). I've checked it a lot of times and I'm pretty sure is not the fault of the COBOL programs (they use quite simple operations). The space in use of that folder is 40%.

Some programs updates the database, and if they finish with return code 0, then the changes are commited, and I don't have any backup, so this is the point of what I'm doing.

This is an example of a file declaration of one of the problematic COBOL programs:

```
FILE-CONTROL.

SELECT MYFILE
   ASSIGN                     TO MYFILE
   ORGANIZATION    IS SEQUENTIAL
   ACCESS MODE     IS SEQUENTIAL
   FILE STATUS     IS FILE-STATUS.

DATA DIVISION.
FILE SECTION.

FD  MYFILE
    LABEL RECORD STANDARD
    RECORDING MODE F.
01  REG-OUTPUT PIC X(400).
```

I've also checked for the nulls in the COBOL programs before the NULL files, but unfortunately there are no nulls spotted.

Then I thought about creating a crontab which executes the following script each 5 seconds:

```
if [[ -f /tmp/sorry_im_working ]]; then
    exit
fi

trap 'rm -rf /tmp/sorry_im_working' EXIT
touch /tmp/sorry_im_working 

lsof | awk 'BEGIN{
    sfiles="";
} {
    if($1=="PROGRAM" && $9~/my_test\/files/){
        sfiles=sfiles" "$9
    }
}END{
    comm="find "sfiles" -newermt \x27-2 seconds\x27 -exec env LC_ALL=C bash -c \x27grep -Pq \x22\x5Cx00{200}\x22 <(tail -c 1000 {}) && echo {}\x27 \x5C\x3B";
    while(comm | getline sout){
        print sout;
    };
    close(comm);
}' >> /home/ouhma/nullfiles.txt
```

Therefore, I would like to ask you the following questions:

1. Any idea of what's going on here?
2. Do you have any other way to trigger the lastest modified files?
3. What other information of interest could I add to my log?

Comment: Is the output directory NFS-mounted?

Comment: I think so. Anyway, I won't be able to access to the server till tomorrow... :(

Comment: If you check a file that is being processed by Microfocus, I am not surprised by the presence of null character. You have to wait the end of the Cobol program to check the output file.

Comment: @V.Michel if checked it a lot of times, and there are not any false positive when checking for nulls in a file which is being written by a COBOL program. Some programs updates the database, and if they finish with return code 0, then the changes are commited, and I don't have any backup, so this is the point of what I'm doing.

Comment: I use Fedora release 23 and i don't have -mtime 1s ( -mtime n : File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago).

Comment: What do you mean by "null character sections"? Might there be something else updating the database at the same time, but which is completed before your re-run? Does it affect multiple output files from the COBOL program, or only one? Does it affect multiple COBOL programs? Generally computers are determinant, so if the program later runs, something about the state for the original run is different. I'd strongly, strongly, suspect the COBOL program rather than the OS/file-system.

Comment: Maybe the null character sections have the size of a record (or a multiple of).

Comment: @BillWoodger programs write the files in sequential mode (all content in only one line). For instance, null chars appears all together in a row, not necesarily when records start and end. And it happens whether program which access database and those which not. COBOL programs are not the cause, believe me. Thanks you all for the ideas, btw.

Comment: @ouhma To find null character, why you don't use grep -Paq '\x00' ?

Comment: Well, bug in RedHat (I'm assuming you are "enterprise") vs bug in COBOL program(s), I know where my money is :-) There's also the COBOL run-time, which is a long way to the left of the applications, and to the right of the OS. A Micro Focus COBOL, or what? I'd ensure the DB is static (copy to a new name) and backed-up. Then "binary chop" the source data for the three-hour run, and try to reproduce. I'd do a lot of stuff like that being thinking it was the OS or the COBOL run-time, both of which are used countless times a day around the world.

Comment: Can you locate the text `LOW-VALUES` or `ALL X'00'` or `ALL H'00'` in the program(s) where this happens? If yes, show the code and the data-definition (the enrire structure). Indeed, why show the structure(s) (record-layout(s)) anyway, and if you can match where the nulls occur to the same position at times, that would also be useful..

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by "checking for nulls in the COBOL program"? I mean exactly what have you checked for. Note that your output file definition is `SEQUENTIAL` where binary values are perfectly valid, rather than `LINE SEQUENTIAL`. Your must have a `WRITE ... FROM ...` or a `MOVE` which involves a more detailed structure than you have in the `FD`. Need to see that, please.

Comment: @dinocob What was the end result? No answer is marked and I found no trace about the "real issue".

Answer (score 0):

If you construct a file d with only \x00 :

```
hexdump -C d
00000000  5c 78 30 30 0a                                    |\x00.|
00000005
```

and you :

```
grep -Faq '\x00' d;echo $?
0
```

But they're no null caracter inside d.

Maybe, is better to use `grep -Paq '\x00'`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the configuration and record structure that is used for the file MF will pad different characters with hex null.

Please copy the 'ASSIGN' clause and the 'FD' clause of the COBOL program.

BTW: if your COBOL programs run three ours to do some calculations and write three GB of data back you should investigate the storage and / or get a COBOL programmer to check the programs, sounds much to slow.

Comment: May account for the nulls, doesn't account for "sometimes it works fine, sometimes it does this".

Comment: Accounts for "sometimes it works" if the data is modified, for example it contains a time stamp...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are have non-printable characters in your file, the null inserts can be controlled, take a look @ [INSERTNULL](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.microfocus.eclipse.infocenter.edtest%2FHRFLRHEXFH1A.html) file configuration.

Comment: May account for the nulls, doesn't account for "sometimes it works fine, sometimes it does this".

Comment: True, my thoughts was that it might reduce the amount of null's so he can see where problem is.

Comment: The registers inserted in the db are ok! The issue is when writing them out to the output file.

Comment: This is the same answer as mine ;-)

Comment: @ouhma, the padding will only occur if the data is written to disk from COBOL via  WRITE not otherwise. Therefore we can better help you if you provide the requested information